# SFTP to SQL import

Tags: sql-server, sftp

I have CSV files stored in SFTP Server which I am accessing using winscp.
I have to import these CSVs into SQL Server tables.
Currently I am downloading files from SFTP and saving them in O Drive and created SSIS packages to import in SQL Server(Using O Drive as source)
How can I import data directly from SFTP server to SQL Server?

I would like to use SSIS for the same but would like to know other methods as well.

Thanks,
AP

Answer (score 2):

There's a free tool called WinSCP which provides a command line utility to communicate with SFTP sites. You just need to understand the scripting language for the command line and execute the executable from SSIS.
Here you can find about this method: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23740/SFTP-with-SSIS-Packages

Another method to load data from SFTP to SQL Server is to use ETL tools, like Skyvia, Alooma, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Powershell script to copy files to an accessible location & then copy contents into a SQL table, not sure if you can skip a step & read the contents directly from the secure location (seem to remember I couldn't get it to work though).

It's a modified version of the powershell example [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles#example), followed by [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) combined with [Out-Datatable](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd) and [Write-DataTable](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2fdeaf8d-b164-411c-9483-99413d6053ae)

There's further WinSCP code examples [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_examples)

Comment: Thanks @Gareth .. Apologies for replying so late. I am not familiar with powershell scripting.But i will give it a try.  To copy files to an accessible location; do i need all the scripts you provided? ( Import-Csv , Out-Datatable and Write-DataTable)